# Java 8: Reference to [method] is ambiguous

Tags: java, generics, compiler-errors, java-8

Does anybody understand why the following code will compile fine in Java 7 and below, but fails with Java 8.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    put(get("hello"));
}

public static <R> R get(String d) {
    return (R)d;
}

public static void put(Object o) {
    System.err.println("Object " + o);
}

public static void put(CharSequence c) {
    System.err.println("CharSequence " + c);
}

public static void put(char[] c) {
    System.err.println("char[] " + c);
}
```

The get method has a generic return type.  In JDK 7 and below this compiles fine and the put method with the Object parameter is chosen.  In JDK 8 this cannot be compiled, indicating the put method is ambiguous.

Apparently JDK 8 is skipping over the Object-parameter method and finding the last two sub-Object-parameter methods and complaining about them (i.e. if you add another put method with some other parameter type, the compiler will switch and complain about the new last two methods)

This seems like a bug.

Comment: Are you sure about this, *compiles fine with Java7 and not Java8* ?

Comment: The `get` method is bogus. What do you expect `R` to be? Inferred from the value assigned to? There are 2 choices when call `put` directly, so which `R` should it use? Hiding an unverified cast behind a generic is really **bad**.

Comment: This does **not** compile in Java 7. Sample code: https://ideone.com/gjzx8G

Comment: This code code compiles without errors on my IDE with Java 8 compiler. There is only a warning about type safety on the casting in return of the generic get method

Comment: @sharonbn It fails when javac is used.

Comment: @sharonbn Which IDE are you using? This code fails for me with Eclipse Mars and Java 8.

Comment: @Amila. I don't understand. I though my IDE (Eclipse) invokes javac. in any case, a cimpiled class can also be executed.

Comment: @Tunaki, Eclipse Luna SR2

Comment: @sharonbn Then I guess that Eclipse improved their compiler in Mars.

Comment: Why cast a `String` generically? `String` is `final` and directly extends `Object` so the only thing you could cast it to is `Object`.

Comment: @Parker, but `String` implements 3 interfaces, so you can also cast it to any of the interfaces...

Comment: @Tunaki This does get compiled with javac 7 in my command line. Perhaps ideone complies using JDK 8 with language level set to Java 7.

Comment: This was not what I was intimating.  Take an untyped map, a map that can take anything as a value.  When getting the values from that map, it would be nice for the compiler to infer the type of the value (e.g. String s = map.get("key"), or Integer i = map.get("key")).  Now when using that returned value with a StringBuilder (e.g. sb.append(map.get("key"))), JDK 7 and below will choose append(Object), while JDK 8 will attempt to choose append(String).  To me this is backwards.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Your problem is a side-effect of **Generalized Target-type Inference**, an improvement in Java 8.

### What is Target-type Inference

Let's take your example method,

```
public static <R> R get(String d) {
    return (R)d;
}
```

Now, in the method above, the generic parameter `R` cannot be resolved by the compiler because there's no parameter with `R`.

So, they introduced a concept called `Target-type Inference`, which allows the parameter to be **inferred** based on the assignment parameter.

So, if you do,

```
 String str = get("something"); // R is inferred as String here
 Number num = get("something"); // R is inferred as Number here
```

This works well in Java 7. But the following **does not**,

```
put(get("something");
static void Put(String str) {} //put method
```

Because type inference worked only for direct assignments.

If there's no direct assignment, then the generic type was **inferred as `Object`**.

So, when you compiled the code with Java 7, your `put(Object)` method was called without any problems.

### What they did in Java 8

They improved the **type inference** to infer the type from **method calls** and **chained method calls**

More details about them [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html) and [here](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/101)

So now, you can directly call `put(get("something"))` and the generic type will be **inferred** based on the **parameter of the `put()` method**.

But as you know, the methods, `put(Charsequence)` and `put(char[])` match the arguments. So there's the ambiguity.

### Fix?

Just tell the compiler exactly what you want,

```
put(TestClass.<CharSequence>get("hello")); // This will call the put(CharSequence) method.
```

Comment: "chained method calls" - do you mean nested method calls? usually "chained" means something like "foo().bar()"

Comment: there are 3 ways to provide target typing - assignment; method arg; casting. so we can solve it with a casting context too - `put( (CharSequence)get("hello") );`

Comment: @bayou.io, I meant chained methods only... If you look at the 2nd link I have included, they have mentioned clearly why it's useful...

Comment: yeah, it would be, but it is not included in java8 :)

Comment: The correct fix is to change that nonsensical `get` method rather than tuning the type inference on it. As long as that method allows `put(TestClass.<char[]>get("hello"));` as well, it’s broken.

Comment: @Ken, check [this SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30521974/why-does-the-java-8-generic-type-inference-pick-this-overload) which explains why Object is not picked. In short, the **most specific** type is inferred.

Comment: I have no problem with it choosing the most specific method, but in the event of a method ambiguity failure, shouldn't the compiler see if there is a less-specific method that can still satisfy the arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this is a known incompatibility.

See "Area: Tools / javac" section of [this article.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-compatibility-guide-2156366.html)
And [this bug](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7144506).

> Synopsis
>
> The following code which compiled, with warnings, in JDK 7 will not compile in JDK 8:

```
import java.util.List;
 
class SampleClass {
 
    static class Baz<T> {
        public static List<Baz<Object>> sampleMethod(Baz<Object> param) {
            return null;
        }
    }
 
    private static void bar(Baz arg) {
        Baz element = Baz.sampleMethod(arg).get(0);
    }
}
```

> Compiling this code in JDK 8 produces the following error:

```
SampleClass.java:12: error:incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to Baz
    Baz element = Baz.sampleMethod(arg).get(0);
                                          
Note: SampleClass.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 error
```

> In this example, a raw type is being passed to the
> sampleMethod(Baz<Object>) method which is applicable by subtyping (see
> the JLS, Java SE 7 Edition, section 15.12.2.2).

> An unchecked
> conversion is necessary for the method to be applicable, so its return
> type is erased (see the JLS, Java SE 7 Edition, section 15.12.2.6). In
> this case the return type of sampleMethod(Baz<Object>) is
> java.util.List instead of java.util.List<Baz<Object>> and thus the
> return type of get(int) is Object, which is not assignment-compatible
> with Baz.

Comment: hmm? this does not seem like an "incompatibility"; it is a bug in javac7, and it is fixed in javac8.