# When called on a derived class, have a generic method defined in base class return derived class type in Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, generics, objectify

I have a utility class for interacting with the Datastore (GAE's in-built Datastore in my case) and it has methods like:

```
//Class GaeDataUtil
public static <T> Optional<Key<T>> saveEntity(T entity)
```

(`Optional` is from the Guava library and `Key<T>` from Objectify, although I doubt any of this makes a difference.)

I want my (minimal) hierarchy of entities to have a `.save()` method. So that for:

```
public class User extends RootEntity
```

where `RootEntity` provides:

```
public Optional<Key<T>> save() {
    //Skipping the error-handling.
    return GaeDataUtil.saveEntity(this);
}
```

I can write:

```
User myUser = new User();
// set some properties
Optional<Key<User>> optKey = myUser.save();
```

But of course that doesn't work because a call to `myUser.save()` returns `Optional<Key<RootEntity>>` not `Optional<Key<User>>` as I want.

I can avoid this issue by typecasting in `User.save()` (and `Account.save()` and `Project.save()` etc. etc.) and suppressing warnings, but even if there are only (say) 10 entity classes extending `RootEntity`, that's still a fair bit of boilerplate code to write *just to typecast*.  Also, I think that much of the benefit of having a class hierarchy is lost if I have to write code (however minimal) for every derived class (there will be other, similar methods too).

Is there a better solution to this?

**Update:** using Java 7.

Comment: This sounds a lot like the use of recursive generics in the Builder pattern - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21086417/builder-pattern-and-inheritance

Comment: My hierarchy is currently very shallow (and likely to stay that way): a `RootEntity` and a number of derived entity classes under that.

Comment: You need to typecast (and suppress unchecked) only in `RootEntity` class. Not all the subclasses.

Comment: @Codebender how would I know which class to typecast to?

Comment: @AndyTurner I changed to `public abstract class RootEntity<T extends RootEntity<T>>` and added `public Optional<Key<T>> save1() {
  return (Optional<Key<T>>) GaeDataUtil.saveEntity(this);
 }` but Eclipse says "Cannot cast from Optional<Key<RootEntity<T>>> to Optional<Key<T>>"

Answer (score 2):

You will just need to type cast it to the Generic type `T` in the `RootEntity.save()` method.

```
public <T> Optional<Key<T>> save() {
    //Skipping the error-handling.
    return (Optional<Key<T>> GaeDataUtil.saveEntity(this); // This line will generate a warning.
}
```

And then when you write,

```
Optional<Key<User>> optKey = myUser.save();
```

It will automatically be inferred correctly because of [**Target Type Inference**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32294457/2775450).

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to parameterize `RootEntity` something like this:

```
class RootEntity<Subclass extends RootEntity> {
  public Optional<Key<Subclass>> save() {...}
}
```

Then define your subclass like:

```
class User extends RootEntity<User> {...}
```

I've used this pattern before.  If there is a slicker solution, I'll be eager to see it.  :)

Comment: This is the correct "work within the system, not around it" answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is what finally worked:

```
public <T extends RootEntity> Optional<Key<T>> save1() {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Key<T> key = (Key<T>) ofy().save().entity(this).now();
    return Optional.fromNullable(key);
}
```

Doing this in two steps works (get the `Key`, then wrap it up in an `Optional`) --- it let's the Target Type Inference work correctly. Doing it in a single step doesn't:

```
public <T extends RootEntity> Optional<Key<T>> save2() {
    return (Optional<Key<T>>) Optional.fromNullable(ofy().save().entity(this).now());
}
```

This second form as suggested by @Codebender shows an error (`Cannot cast from Optional<Key<RootEntity>> to Optional<Key<T>>`), not a warning in Eclipse.

[image: Target Type Inference works if done in two steps]

However, the basic idea by @Codebender of using Target Type Inference was sound.

Comment: With your original `static` method `saveEntity`, there was a restriction on `T` as it has to be compatible with the type of the `entity` parameter. With your new `save1` instance method, there is no restriction on `T`, the caller can infer *anything* for `T` without getting a compiler warning. In other words, your method promises to return an `Optional<Key<WhatEverTheCallerLikes>>` which it can’t hold. In the programming world, we call such a design a fatal accident waiting to happen…