# Generic Type Mismatch

Tags: java

```
class GenMethDemo {
    static <T, V extends T> boolean isIn(T x, V[] y) {
        for (int i = 0; i < y.length; i++)
            if (x.equals(y[i]))
                return true;
        return false;
    }

    /*when compiled in java 7 it producing an error and compiling in java 8 without error */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Integer nums[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        String s[] = {"one", "two", "three"};
        System.out.println(isIn("fs", nums));
      /*
      when compiled in java 7 it producing an error and compiling in java 8 without error */
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show *text* describing the problem. In particular, what error do you get in Java 7?

Comment: `isIn("fs", nums)` shouldn't work since in that case `T` will be `String` and `V` will be `Integer` which does not extend `String`. However Java 8 type inference might be more lenient in that it tries to find a match which would be `T = Object` and `V = Object`.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the Generalized Target-type Inference improvements in Java 8.  Actually, I answered a question similar to this last week.  [Java 8 call to generic method is ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36008296/java-8-call-to-generic-method-is-ambiguous/36008895#36008895)

The first answer of the question [Java 8: Reference to [method] is ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32294140/java-8-reference-to-method-is-ambiguous) is also very good.

Java 8 is able infer the type of arguments passed to a generic method.  So as @Thomas said in his comment, the type `T` is inferred to be an `Object`, and `V` is inferred to be an object that extends `Object`, so `Integer`.  In Java 7, this would just throw an error as `Integer` clearly doesn't extend `String`.

Answer (score 0):

In Java 7 type inference would see `T = String` and `V = Integer` which won't satisfy `V extends T`.

However, the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html) for Java 8 states that this would work:

```
List<Number> ln = Arrays.asList(1, 2.0);
```

Thus in your case this would be resolved to `T = V = Object`.