# java extending Generic types ambiguous method call

Tags: java, generics

I have run into a problem which is hard for me to understand why this happens.

I have a generic class B which extends generic class A and i have two methods accepting A and B. From method accepting A i want to call method with paramter B 
but this results in compilation error:

> Ambiguous method call. Both method (A) in Main and method
>   (B) in Main match

Here is a code snippet:

```
public class Main {

private static class A<T> {

}

private static class B<T> extends A {

}

public String method(A<String> arg) {
    return method((B<String>) arg));
}

public String method(B<String> arg) {
    return "some result";
}
}
```

However if I remove generic type from type A it compiles:

```
public class Main {

private static class A<T> {

}

private static class B<T> extends A {

}

public String method(A arg) {
    return method((B<String>) arg));
}

public String method(B<String> arg) {
    return "some result";
}
}
```

What is the reason of that ?

Edit:
This issue is somehow related to java 8 because this code is compilable with JDK7

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compiler error : reference to call ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14053596/compiler-error-reference-to-call-ambiguous) OR [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32294140/java-8-reference-to-method-is-ambiguous)

Comment: Well, it does not quite make sense on what you are doing.  Anyway: `A<String>` is-NOT-a `A<Object>`  .  As you declare your `B<T> extends A`, which means `B<T> extends A<Object>`, which means, `B<WhateverType>` is-a `A<Object>`.  Given `A<Object>` is-NOT-a `A<String>`, `B<String>` is-NOT-a `A<String>`, so the compiler is actually complaining it correctly by avoiding you to cast from `A<String>` to `B<String>` as it will never be lega

Answer (score 2):

Your class `B` extends `A` but it's not specifying its bounds nor any generic info

What I mean is that your line

```
private static class B<T> extends A { ... }
```

is equivalent to

```
private static class B<T> extends A<Object> { ... }
```

By changing it to

```
private static class B<T> extends A<T> { ... }
```

Your code will compile

Comment: You are right it will compile but what if i don't want them to share the types ? I cast the parameter to B to explicitly call the other method but it looks like compiler ignores it