# Java compiler choosing wrong overload

Tags: java

```
@Test
public void test() {
    MyProperties props = new MyProperties();
    props.setProperty("value", new Date());

    StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(props.getProperty("value"));
}

public class MyProperties {
    private Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    public void setProperty(String name, Object value) {
        properties.put(name, value);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> T getProperty(String name) {
        return (T) properties.get(name);
    }
}

public class StringUtils {

    public static boolean isNullOrEmpty(Object string) {
        return isNullOrEmpty(valueOf(string));
    }

    public static String valueOf(Object string) {
        if (string == null) {
            return "";
        }
        return string.toString();
    }

    public static boolean isNullOrEmpty(String string) {
        if (string == null || string.length() == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        int strLength = string.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < strLength; i++) {
            char charAt = string.charAt(i);
            if (charAt > ' ') {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

For years, this unit test has been passing. Then after upgrading to Java 8, in certain environments, when the code is compiled via javac, it chooses the StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(String) overload.  This causes the unit test to fail with the following error message:

`java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at com.foo.bar.StringUtils_UT.test(StringUtils_UT.java:35)`

The unit tests passes when compiled and run on my machine via ant (ant 1.9.6, jdk_8_u60, Windows 7 64bit) but fails on another with the same versions of ant and java (ant 1.9.6 jdk_8_u60, Ubuntu 12.04.4 32bit).

Java's [type inference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html), which chooses the most specific overload from all applicable overloads when compiling, has been changed in Java 8. I assume my issue has something to do with this.

I know the compiler sees the return type of the MyProperties.getProperty(...) method as T, not Date. Since the compiler doesn't know the return type of the getProperty(...) method, why is it choosing StringUtils.isNullorEmpty(String) instead of StringUtils.isNullorEmpty(Object) - which should always work?

Is this a bug in Java or just a result of Java 8's type inference changes?  Also, why would different environments using the same version of java compile this code differently?

Comment: In your case all Java-8 JREs should choose the `StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(String)` overload only.. Check [this SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30521974/why-does-the-java-8-generic-type-inference-pick-this-overload) which talks about which overload will be picked in this case...

Comment: To be honest `getProperty` looks like a bad joke to me. Even though it looks like a problem in Java 8, it is good that you now pay some attention to that smelly code. Since you're not using any other type for *value* except `Object`, `T` can't be nothing else than `Object`. Can you explain what magic you expect to happen with `T`? If not, then remove it and just return `properties.get(name)` as `Object`. Btw ignoring a warning is rarely a good idea :).

Comment: Yep, your code has been broken all along, but it _happened_ to work. Now it's payback time.

Answer (score 7):

This code *smells*.  Yes, this passes under Java 7, and yes it runs alright with Java 7, but there is something *definitely wrong* here.

First, let's talk about this generic type.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T> T getProperty(String name) {
    return (T) properties.get(name);
}
```

Can you at a glance infer what `T` *should* be?  If I run those casts in Java 7 compliance mode with IntelliJ at that exact line, I get back this very helpful `ClassCastException`:

> `Cannot cast java.util.Date to T`

So this implies that at some level, Java knew there was something off here, but it elected to change that cast instead from `(T)` to `(Object)`.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T> Object getProperty(String name) {
    return (Object) properties.get(name);
}
```

In this case, the cast is redundant, and you get back an `Object` from the map, as you would expect.  Then, the correct overload is called.

Now, in Java 8, things are a  bit more sane; since you don't truly provide a type to the `getProperty` method, it blows up, since it *really* can't cast `java.util.Date` to `T`.

---

Ultimately, I'm glossing over the main point:

## This use of generics is broken and incorrect.

You don't even *need* generics here.  Your code can handle either a `String` or an `Object`, and your map only contains `Object`s anyway.

You should only return `Object` from the `getProperty` method, since that's what you can only return from your map anyhow.

```
public Object getProperty(String name) {
    return properties.get(name);
}
```

It does mean that you no longer get the ability to call *directly* into the method with a signature of `String` (since you're passing an `Object` in now), but it does mean that your broken generics code can finally be put to rest.

---

If you *really* want to preserve this behavior though, you would have to introduce a new parameter into your function that actually allowed you to specify which type of object you wanted back from your map.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T> T getProperty(String name, Class<T> clazz) {
    return (T) properties.get(name);
}
```

Then you could invoke your method thus:

```
StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(props.getProperty("value", Date.class));
```

Now we are absolutely certain as to what `T` is, and Java 8 is content with this code.  This is still a bit of a smell, since you're storing things in a `Map<String, Object>`; if you've got the `Object` overridden method and you can guarantee that all objects in that map have a meaningful `toString`, then I would personally avoid the above code.

Comment: He's presumably casting String to Object when putting them into the map.  However, overloading works on the declared type, not the class's actual type.  Presumably, the Generics usage was an attempt to get it to call the correct type, instead of just using `instanceof` inside isNullOrEmpty.

Comment: No, there's no casting on insertion going on at all.  At least, that's what the test indicates. If that behavior is actually happening, then it should have been captured in the test.

Comment: That was bad wording on my part as you don't need to cast something to pass it to a method that takes an Object (for setProperty).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all.

Answer (score 2):

Java 8 does have improved [target type inference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html#target_types).  This means that the compiler will use the target type to infer the type parameter.

In your case, this means that in this statement

```
StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(props.getProperty("value"));
```

Java will use the parameter type of `isNullOrEmpty` to determine the type parameter of the `getProperty` method.  But there are 2 overloads of `isNullOrEmpty`, one taking an `Object` and one taking a `String`.  There is no bound on `T`, so the compiler will choose the most specific method that matches -- the overload that takes a `String`.  `T` is inferred to be `String`.

Your cast to `T` is unchecked, so the compiler allows it, but it gives you an unchecked cast warning about casting an `Object` to a `T`.  However, when the `isNullOrEmpty` method is called, the class cast exception is thrown, because the original object was really a `Date`, which can't be converted to a `String`.

This illustrates the dangers of ignoring the unchecked cast warning.

This didn't occur in Java 7, because the improved target type inference didn't exist.  The compiler inferred `Object`.

The improved target type inference in Java 8 has revealed that your `getProperty` method is incorrectly ignoring the unchecked cast warning that you're suppressing with `@SuppressWarnings`.

To fix this, don't even have an overloaded method that takes a `String`.  Move the `String`-specific logic inside the overload that takes an `Object`.

```
public static boolean isNullOrEmpty(Object o) {
    // null instanceof String is false
    String string = (o instanceof String) ? ((String) o) : valueOf(o);
    if (string == null || string.length() == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    int strLength = string.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < strLength; i++) {
        char charAt = string.charAt(i);
        if (charAt > ' ') {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Of course this means that the generics on the `getProperty` method are meaningless.  Remove them.

```
public Object getProperty(String name) {
    return properties.get(name);
}
```

Comment: ....which makes sense if you think about it.  After all, if you're using Generics, how often do you set the generic type as `Object`?  Literally, the only reason to do that is to avoid the compiler warning for not using non-generic types.

Comment: I have a vague memory about some kind of release note for Java 8 about this change of behaviour of the compiler but now don't seem to be able to find it. Bonus point if you can provide a link to it!

Comment: @Lii Go to the duplicate question to get all the glorious detail. You'll probably regret your curiosity, though.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Ah, that old question! I love those weird little details! I found the link to the release notes, it was the [Compatibility Guide](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-compatibility-guide-2156366.html).