# Java 8 type inference bug?

Tags: java, generics, java-8

I know that similar type inference questions have been posted before ([Java compiler choosing wrong overload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32507155/java-compiler-choosing-wrong-overload) or [Why does the Java 8 generic type inference pick this overload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30521974/why-does-the-java-8-generic-type-inference-pick-this-overload)) but I think we picked a more interesting case here.

```
public class TemplateMethod {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));
        method("a", "b");
        method("a", 5);
        method("a", new B().get());
    }


    public static void method(String s, String cause) {
        System.out.println("String");        
    }

    public static void method(String s, Object parameters) {
        System.out.println("Object");
    }

    public static interface Base {
        String methodToImplement();
    }

    public static class Impl implements Base {
        public String methodToImplement() {
            return "Impl.methodToImplement";
        }
    }

    public static class B {
        public <T extends Base> T get() {
            return (T) new Impl();
        }
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
TemplateMethod$Impl cannot be cast to java.lang.String at
TemplateMethod.main(TemplateMethod.java:9)
```

What I cannot understand here, that if the return type is `T extends Base` how can `String` be candidate for the return type?

The previous questions on StackOverflow do not deal with the special case with generics like here so I think this is **not** a duplicate. At those cases mentioned above the Java8 compiler behaves as the language specification is written. In this case I think that is not the case, the signature `method(String, String)` should not need to be considered for the return type of `T <T extends Base>` since a `String` will never be a `TemplateMethod.Base` defined here.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. Do you have the latest update?

Comment: :o I stand corrected it seems

Comment: Replicated with JDK 1.8.0_45 and 1.8.0_102. Trying with latest...

Comment: Replicated with jdk 1.8.0_51 on ideone: http://ideone.com/ZwSZOw

Comment: I ran it on JKD 1.8.0_51 and it ran fine. Compiled and ran it under Eclipse Mars.

Comment: Ran with 1.8.0_u60 and u102, both had the ClassCastException.

Comment: Interesting, we have a working and an exception throwing version both with u51? Buhake on what platform did you succeed?

Comment: @mpocsaji on Windows. Like I said, I compiled it and ran it using the IDE.

Comment: Apart from editing the question (see last paragraph) how can I convince SO admins that this is not a duplicate? Am I the only one thinking this is a different question from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30521974/why-does-the-java-8-generic-type-inference-pick-this-overload ?

Comment: Thanks @BuhakeSindi - my platform is Linux. Trying to check with colleagues working on Windows platform as well.

Comment: It is *exactly* the same issue as in the linked question or like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28474319/2711488). You only have to face the fact that if your method `get()` promises to return whatever subtype of `Base` the caller wants, then the caller/compiler can say “Ok, the gimme `X extends String&Base`”. The fact that your method cannot hold the promise, is *your* problem, not the problem of the language or compiler.

Comment: @Holger, class String is final so there cannot be a class which `extends String implements Base`. This is a **fact** during compile-time as well. Hence, I still think that the signature `(String, String)` should be out of question during compile-time.

Comment: Just because a class is `final` at compile time, it doesn’t imply that it has to be `final` at runtime. Just because a class doesn’t implement `Base` at compile time, it doesn’t imply that it won’t implement `Base` at runtime. Anyway, that’s not important. There are *rules*. And just because *you* think that something should be out of question, it doesn’t change the rules. The rule is, if your method promises to return `String&Base`, if the caller wishes, accept it, even if the promise can’t be held. Hey, your method is broken for *any* type other than `Impl`, `final` or not.

Comment: Other examples for surprising intersection types incorporating `final` classes are [here (`String&List`)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38092697/2711488) and [here (`Integer&CharSequence`)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36402646/2711488).