# Why does the compiler choose this generic method with a class type parameter when invoked with an unrelated interface type?

Tags: java, generics, java-8, language-lawyer, javac

Consider the following two classes and interface:

```java
public class Class1 {}
public class Class2 {}
public interface Interface1 {}
```

Why does the second call to `mandatory` invoke the overloaded method with `Class2`, if `getInterface1` and `Interface1` have no relationship with `Class2`?

```java
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class1 class1 = getClass1();
        Interface1 interface1 = getInterface1();

        mandatory(getClass1());     // prints "T is not class2"
        mandatory(getInterface1()); // prints "T is class2"
        mandatory(class1);          // prints "T is not class2"
        mandatory(interface1);      // prints "T is not class2"
    }

    public static <T> void mandatory(T o) {
        System.out.println("T is not class2");
    }

    public static <T extends Class2> void mandatory(T o) {
        System.out.println("T is class2");
    }

    public static <T extends Class1> T getClass1() {
        return null;
    }

    public static <T extends Interface1> T getInterface1() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I understand that Java 8 [broke compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30521974/why-does-the-java-8-generic-type-inference-pick-this-overload) with Java 7:

```
$ /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac -source 1.7 -target 1.7 *java; /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java Test
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.7
1 warning
T is not class2
T is not class2
T is not class2
T is not class2
```

And with Java 8 (also tested with 11 and 13):

```
$ /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac *java; /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java Test                        
T is not class2
T is class2
T is not class2
T is not class2
```

Comment: Bottom line: method overloading in Java brings so many surprises, it should be used with extreme care only. Discriminating two overloads only by a bound of a type parameter is asking for trouble, as demonstrated by the complexity of the answer. You are basically asking each reader of your code to read and understand that answer before they can understand your code. Put differently: if your program breaks when type inference is improved, you are not on safe territory. Good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rules of type inference have received a significant overhaul in Java 8, most notably target type inference has been much improved. So, whereas before Java 8 the method argument site did not receive any inference, defaulting to erased type (`Class1` for `getClass1()` and `Interface1` for `getInterface1()`), in Java 8 the most specific applicable type is inferred. The JLS for Java 8 introduced a new chapter [Chapter 18. Type Inference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html) that's missing in JLS for Java 7.

---

The most specific applicable type for `<T extends Interface1>` is `<X extends RequiredClass & BottomInterface>`, where `RequiredClass` is a class required by a context, and `BottomInterface` is a bottom type for all interfaces (including `Interface1`).

Note: Each Java type can be represented as `SomeClass & SomeInterfaces`. Since `RequiredClass` is sub-type of `SomeClass`, and `BottomInterface` is sub-type of `SomeInterfaces`, `X` is sub-type of every Java type. Therefore, `X` is a Java bottom type.

`X` matches both `public static <T> void mandatory(T o)` and `public static <T extends Class2> void mandatory(T o)` methods signatures since `X` is Java bottom type.

So, according to [§15.12.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2), `mandatory(getInterface1())` calls the most specific overloading of `mandatory()` method, which is `public static <T extends Class2> void mandatory(T o)` since `<T extends Class2>` is more specific than `<T>`.

Here is how you can explicitly specify `getInterface1()` type parameter to make it return the result that matches `public static <T extends Class2> void mandatory(T o)` method signature:

```
public static <T extends Class2 & Interface1> void helper() {
    mandatory(Test.<T>getInterface1()); // prints "T is class2"
}
```

---

The most specific applicable type for `<T extends Class1>` is `<Y extends Class1 & BottomInterface>`, where `BottomInterface` is a bottom type for all interfaces.

`Y` matches `public static <T> void mandatory(T o)` method signature, but it doesn't match `public static <T extends Class2> void mandatory(T o)` method signature since `Y` doesn't extend `Class2`.

So `mandatory(getClass1())` calls `public static <T> void mandatory(T o)` method.

Unlike with `getInterface1()`, you can't explicitly specify `getClass1()` type parameter to make it return the result that matches `public static <T extends Class2> void mandatory(T o)` method signature:

```
                       java: interface expected here
                                     ↓
public static <T extends Class1 & C̲l̲a̲s̲s̲2> void helper() {
    mandatory(Test.<T>getClass1());
}
```